# MySQL on Windows Refuses to Start as a Service

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, windows-server

I am trying to install MySQL 5.7.33 onto a windows 2012 server. A process I have done many many times.
I have copied the Zip file onto the server and expanded it into `G:/mysql57/` (the same zip file I used to install on other servers previously without issues).

I place a `my.ini` file into this directory. Then I initialize the database:

`G:/mysql57/bin/mysqld.exe --initialize --basedir=G:/mysql57/ --datadir=G:/mysql57/data/`

So far so good. The error log is created along with temporary password. I then install the service:

`G:/mysql57/bin/mysqld.exe --install MySQL57 --defaults-file="G:/mysql57/my.ini"`

I then try to start the service, which results in:

`Error 1053: The service did not respond in a timely fashion`

It also annoyingly doesn't add anything to the error log.

If I try and run mysqld manually however it works fine, no errors

`G:/mysql57/bin/mysqld.exe --defaults-file=G:/mysql57/my.ini`

I can log in, I change my password etc.

Yet starting the service fails, every time.

I should point out that there is another MySQL database on there in `D:/mysql` (MySQL 5.5) which is using port 3306 and runs fine. This new one is using Port 3307.
Again a process I have done many times over.

I have checked the Windows Event Viewer, nothing.
I have tried the `my.ini` file from the old database.
I have tried a minimal `my.ini` file (port, basedir and datadir only).

Still nothing.

Is there anything else I have missed, as I've now lost most of a day on something that was supposed to be done by lunchtime.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it all came down to the " " which it didn't like.

So I changed:

`G:/mysql57/bin/mysqld.exe --install MySQL57 --defaults-file="G:/mysql57/my.ini"`

to

`G:/mysql57/bin/mysqld.exe --install MySQL57 --defaults-file=G:/mysql57/my.ini`

and it started up straight away. I can only assume this is something to do with Windows Server 2012, as I repeated the whole process (with " ") on my Windows 10 PC, and it worked fine.